# El looper se detiene

Tags: firebase, kotlin, bucles

Tengo una aplicación la cual recibe notificaciones por firebase y las guarda en directamente a diferentes secciones de sharedPreference. Al enviar una notificación esta la recibe mi aplicacion y me lo muestra en un Toast, pero al querer recibir una segunda no lo hace. Y solo la muestra cuando vuelvo a correr el emulador.

Temo que el problema esta en el Looper y Handler que se encuentran mal empleados

Este es mi codigo

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService() {


private lateinit var shared: SharedPreferences
private lateinit var editor:SharedPreferences.Editor

private val COUNT_KEY = "Conteo"


override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {



    Looper.prepare()
        Handler().post{
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, remoteMessage.notification?.title + "\n"
                    +remoteMessage.notification?.body, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


            shared = getSharedPreferences("Notificaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                var count = shared.getInt(COUNT_KEY,0)
                    count++
                editor = shared.edit()
                editor.putString("Titulo${count}", remoteMessage.notification?.title)
                editor.putString("Cuerpo${count}", remoteMessage.notification?.body)
                editor.putString("Fecha${count}", remoteMessage.notification?.eventTime.toString())
                editor.apply()
            //guardando las variables de shared preferences
                editor.putInt(COUNT_KEY, count).apply()

        }
    Looper.loop()





}
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar lo agradecería en grande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?hl=es), el método onMessageReceived sólo se ejecuta si la app está en primer plano, si la app está en segundo plano, o no se está ejecutando, la carga útil se entregará en los extras del intent, la notificación a la bandeja del sistema y onMessageReceived no se ejecutará.

Para garantizar que todos tus mensajes ejecuten el método onMessageReceived debes enviar Data Messages exclusivamente (sin notificación), toda la información que requieras procesar deberá viajar en el objeto "data", incluyendo la información necesaria para que despliegues tu notificación manualmente si así lo requieres.

Si lo anterior no resuelve tu problema, prueba con el siguiente código:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Origen: ${remoteMessage.from}")

    // Revisa si hay datos
    if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
        //Aqui viajaría toda la información si decides sólo usar data messages
        Log.d(TAG, "Carga util: ${remoteMessage.data}") 
    }

    if (/* Comprueba si el manejo de los datos va a tomar mucho tiempo*/) {
            // Para tareas de largo tiempo de ejecución (10+ seg) utiliza WorkManager.
            scheduleJob()
    } else {
            // Si tu task dura menos de 10s no es necesario utilizar looper
            handleNow(remoteMessage)
    }
}

 
private fun scheduleJob() {​
  WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(
      OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker::class.java).build());
}

private fun handleNow(remoteMessage:RemoteMessage) {​
    // Revisa si el mensaje contiene una notificación
    Toast.makeText(baseContext, remoteMessage.notification?.title + "\n"
                +remoteMessage.notification?.body, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    val shared = getSharedPreferences("Notificaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            var count = shared.getInt(COUNT_KEY,0)
                count++
    val editor = shared.edit()
    editor.putString("Titulo${count}", remoteMessage.notification?.title)
    editor.putString("Cuerpo${count}", remoteMessage.notification?.body)
    editor.putString("Fecha${count}", remoteMessage.notification?.eventTime.toString())
    editor.putInt(COUNT_KEY, count)
    //apply escribe los datos introducidos en Background, por lo que no es necesario meterlo en otro hilo
    editor.apply()
}
```

Comment: onMessageReceived() no solo se ejecuta en primer plano, las aplicaciones deberìan estar abiertas siempre para recibir notificaciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudó bastante para comprender la data en las notificaciones